# How to run php code when inotify event is triggered

Tags: php, inotify

I am trying to reload a frame whenever a file (log.txt) is updated in php. I think I can do this with `inotify_add_watch($inf, './log.txt', IN_MODIFY);`.

The thing is, I am a complete php noob, and the docs didn't help with this one.
How would I go about running some code when the file IN_MODIFY event is triggered?

So far, i have

```html
<html style='background-color:#202020;'>
  <word style='color:#FFFFFF;'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2"/>
  </head>
  <body id="chat">
  <?php
    $log = file_get_contents('./log.txt');
    echo $log;
    $inf = inotify_init();
    $watch = inotify_add_watch($inf, './log.txt', IN_MODIFY);
    $events = inotify_read($inf);
    //Run php code here when inotify event occurs

    inotify_rm_watch($inf, $watch);
    fclose($inf);
  ?>
 </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I have the watch descriptor and inotify instance set up, but I have no clue how to use the event.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you read the fine manual about inotify? It starts here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.inotify.php, with a nice section: [inotify_read](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.inotify-read.php) — Read events from an inotify instance

Comment: Oh, that was it? Haha thanks.